# c++ comparing two floating point values

Tags: c++, floating-point

I'm wondering what is the difference for comparing two double between this two manner :

```
double a1 = ...;
double a2 = ....;
```

1. fabs(a1-a2) < epsilon
2. (fabs(a1-a2)/a2) < epsilon

Is there a prefering way to do that ?

thanks

Comment: The "prefering way" heavily depends on the surrounding algorithm. Both have their use (and also the more verbose `fabs(a1 - a2) / min(a1, a2)` and `fabs(a1 - a2) / max(a1, a2)`, and especially `max(fabs(a1 - a2), fabs(a1 - a2) / a1)` when you don't know a priori if the numbers are close to zero or not).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[This article](http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/) answers your question quite thoroughly, I think. You might want to skip ahead to the section "Epsilon comparisons".

Comment: Added quote from linked article, hope you don't mind, feel free to rollback if you desire.

Comment: I worry that that quote is not really answering his question: I think he's aware of the precision issue, just asking why divide by a2. I considered quoting something originally, but I think the article is better left intact. I've rolled-back and edited to indicate the section most relevant.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I'm using `std::nextafter` for comparing two `double`. This use the smallest `epsilon` on a value (or a `factor` of the smallest `epsilon`).

```
bool nearly_equal(double a, double b)
{
  return std::nextafter(a, std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest()) <= b
    && std::nextafter(a, std::numeric_limits<double>::max()) >= b;
}

bool nearly_equal(double a, double b, int factor /* a factor of epsilon */)
{
  double min_a = a - (a - std::nextafter(a, std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest())) * factor;
  double max_a = a + (std::nextafter(a, std::numeric_limits<double>::max()) - a) * factor;

  return min_a <= b && max_a >= b;
}
```

Comment: The result of `nearly_equal(..,..,epsilon)` does not equal to : `fabs(right-left) < epsilon` ?

Comment: `nearly_equal(a, b, factor)` checks equality with tolerance of `factor * epsilon(a)`. `fabs(a-b) < epsilon` checks equality with tolerance of a given `epsilon`. Both expressions are good and can be used according to what we would like to test. Sometime, we want to check with a fixed epsilon (even if it's difficult to find a correct epsilon: epsilon (1e20) = 16384). Sometime, we want to check with a factor of epsilon (even if it's also difficult to find a correct factor). Now for `fabs(a-b) < fabs(a) * epsilon`, it would be more accurate to use `nearly_equal(a, b, epsilon)` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Epsilon varies according to the value inside the double range. If you want to use your **own** and **fixed** epsilon, I recommand to choose an epsilon for `1`.

```
fabs(a1-a2) < epsilon
```

This is not perfect. If `a1` and `a2` are results from operations with small numbers, the epsilon would be small. If `a1` and `a2` are results from operations with big numbers, the epsilon would be big.

```
fabs((a1-a2)/a2) < epsilon
```

This is a bit better as you would like to scale `epsilon` by `a2`. However, there is a division by `0` if `a2` equals `0`.

```
fabs(a1-a2) < fabs(a2)*epsilon
```

This is a bit better. However, this is incorrect if `a2` equals `0`. `fabs(a2)*epsilon` would be equal to `0` and the comparison of two values `a1=0.000000001` and `a2=0` will always fail.

```
fabs(a1-a2) < max(fabs(a1), fabs(a2))*epsilon
```

This is a bit better. However, this is incorrect because `epsilon` is not proportional in **continuous** manner. With IEEE encoding, `epsilon` is proportional to a value in **discrete** manner on base `2`.

```
fabs(a1-a2) < 2^((int)log2(max(fabs(a1), fabs(a2)))*epsilon
```

This looks correct for me when both `a1` and `a2` are not equal to `0`.

The implementation of a generic method could be:

```
bool nearly_equal(double a1, double a2, double epsilon)
{
  if (a1 == 0 && a2 == 0)
    return true;

  return std::abs(a1 - a2) < epsilon * pow (2.0, static_cast<int> (std::log2(std::max(std::abs(a1), std::abs(a2)))));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The former only compares the absolute values, whereas the second compares the relative values. Say that epsilon is set to `0.1`: this may be sufficient if `a1` and `a2` are largish. However, if both values are close to zero, the first way will consider most values equal.

It really depends on what kinds of values you are dealing with. Just be sure to consider the case `a2==0` if you use the somewhat more mathematically reasonable second case.

Answer (score 2):

This has already been pretty well addressed, but a few points are in order:

```
fabs(a1-a2) < epsilon
```

is comparing the **absolute difference** between `a1` and `a2` to the tolerance `epsilon`.  This may be appropriate if you know the scaling *a priori* (for example, if `a2` is actually a constant), but should generally be avoided if you don't know how big `a1` and `a2` are.

Your second option almost computes the **relative difference**, but has a bug; it should actually read:

```
fabs((a1-a2)/a2) < epsilon
```

(note that the division is *inside* the absolute value; otherwise, this condition is useless for negative `a2`).  Relative error is more correct for most uses, because it more closely mirrors the way floating-point rounding actually happens, but there are situations in which it does not work and you need to use an absolute tolerance (usually this is because of *catastrophic cancellation*).  You also will sometimes see relative error bounds written in this form:

```
fabs(a1-a2) < fabs(a2)*epsilon
```

which is often somewhat more efficient because it avoids a division.

Comment: really like the last form, don't really understand in which case it doesn"t work

Comment: If my number are 10e-7 to 10e6 which epsilon value should I used ?

Comment: @Guillaume07: If the values are spread over that large of a range, you certainly want to use one of the relative error comparisons (the 2nd or 3rd options that I listed).  The more subtle question is "how do I choose an appropriate value of epsilon?"

Comment: Note that when doing a relative difference epsilon comparison you should not just blindly divide by a2 (or a1). If you do that then you get asymmetries where compare(a,b) gives different results from compare(b,a). That would be bad.

You need to consistently divide by the number with the largest or smallest absolute value. Something like this:

auto largest = max(fabs(a1),fabs(a2));
return fabs(a1-a2) < fabs(largest)*epsilon;