# Performance: toFixed() vs. Math.floor(x * 10000)

Tags: javascript

I need to compare two float values to a certain precision (that is 4 decimal places):

```
var float1 = 0.0025132741228718345;
var float2 = 0.0025132812393818293;
```

The two options I see:

```
Math.floor(float1 * 10000) === Math.floor(float2 * 10000); // 25 === 25
```

...or:

```
float1.toFixed(4) === float2.toFixed(4) // "0.0025" === "0.0025"
```

Since operation will happen 60 times a second and I was asking myself:

1. which of the options has the higher performance?
2. is one of the options more widely accepted?
3. is there a third option?

Comment: Third option would be `abs(float1 - float2)<0.00001`. It is widely accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function floor(f1, f2) {
    return Math.floor(f1 * 10000) === Math.floor(f2 * 10000);
}
function toFixed(f1, f2) {
    return f1.toFixed(4) === f2.toFixed(4);
}
function subtract(f1, f2) {
    return Math.abs(f1 - f2) < 0.00001;
}
function test(fn) {
     console.time(fn.name);
     for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
         fn(Math.random(), Math.random());
     }
     console.timeEnd(fn.name);
}
for (const fn of [floor, toFixed, subtract]) {
    test(fn);
}
```

## Engine benchmarks

### v8 (Chromium-based browsers)

- floor: 204.911 ms
- toFixed: 4145.529 ms
- subtract: 292.390 ms

### SpiderMonkey (Firefox-based browsers)

- floor: 566.81ms
- toFixed: 683.56ms
- subtract: 423.76ms

Between the two options that you gave, The `Math.floor` approach is the faster one.

Might be a wise choice to go for `subtract`, though.

(Run this benchmark yourself if you don't believe me.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Why might it be a wise choice to go for `substract`?

Comment: Because the results for `subtract` have the lowest arithmetic mean across the two engines I've tested, in relation to all other implementations (note that `floor` isn't the fastest on Firefox-based browsers).

Comment: @kraftwer1 With floor, 0.00250 is equal to 0.00259 but is not equal to 0.00249, even though 0.00249 is much closer to 0.00250. That's the reason you should probably go with [epsilon comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064377/c-comparing-two-floating-point-values) (reffred to as "subtract" in this answer).

Comment: (Another typical name for this to research would be "fuzzy equals".)

Comment: I prefer `subtract()` too. It is based on the distance of both numbers. The alternatives divide the numbers into classes. So for very near numbers (e.g. difference 1e-10) the result may be FALSE, but difference 1e-6 becomes TRUE.

Answer (score 4):

Fast version:

```js
function FastFloor(f1, f2) {
  return ~~(f1 * 10000) === ~~(f2 * 10000);
}
```

BenchMark:
[enter link description here](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/5545/0/tofixed-vs-toprecision-vs-mathround-vs-mathfloorfast)

Answer (score 1):

```
Math.round(142.89 * 100) / 100 // 142.89
Math.floor(142.89 * 100) / 100 // 142.88
```

it seems the toFixed based on the round function, so better use it instead