# Does floating-point use a key in hashtable?

Tags: c++, stl, floating-point

I know that floating-point values cannot be compared by ==. I have made a custom comparison function like this.

```
auto isEqual = [](const double& a, const double& b) {
  return fabs(a-b) <= numeric_limits<double>::epsilon();
};
```

I would like to know how I modify the unordered map to be worked as I expected.

```
auto isEqual = [](const double& a, const double& b) {
  return fabs(a-b) <= numeric_limits<double>::epsilon();
};

unordered_map<double, int, hash<double>, decltype(isEqual)> m(0, hash<double>(), isEqual);
m[1/(double)3]++;
cout << m[1-2/(double)3] << endl; // expected 1, but zero

// -----------------------------

auto comp = [&](const double& a, const double& b) {
  if (isEqual(a, b)) return false;
  return a < b;
};

map<double, int, decltype(comp)> m2(comp);
m2[1/(double)3]++;
cout << m2[1-2/(double)3] << endl;  // expected and answered 1
```

Comment: Note that `epsilon` on its own isn't a good test for equality, e.g see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064377/c-comparing-two-floating-point-values

Comment: Re “floating-point values cannot be compared by ==“ — they can. Your “nearly equals” function has one horrible property: it’s not transitive. If `a` “nearly equals” `b` and `b` “nearly equals” `c` you cannot conclude that `a` “nearly equals” `c`. Your map lookups will give you very confusing answers.

Answer (score 2):

It is essentially impossible to modify an `unordered_map` to use floating-point values that contain different rounding errors as keys.

Customizing the equality comparison alone is insufficient because it is merely used to distinguish values that are mapped to the same bucket by the hash function. Different floating-point values generally hash to different buckets, even if they differ only by the tiniest of rounding errors. Therefore, one must also customize the hash function.

However, then the requirement for the hash function would be that it map floating-point values that are different but that you would like to consider as equal to the same bucket. In general, this is impossible because, if you want to consider any two very close numbers as equal, say numbers that are so close that they are adjacent in the floating-point format, then transitivity requires the hash function to map all numbers to one bucket. That is, since zero and the smallest positive representable number must map to the same bucket, and the smallest and second smallest positive representable numbers must map to the same bucket, then zero and the second smallest positive representable number must map to the same bucket. Similarly, the third smallest number must represent to the same bucket as the second smallest and therefore to the same bucket as zero. And so on for the fourth and fifth. This creates a chain that continues for all numbers: They must all map to the same bucket.

Therefore, no hash function can serve to implement a non-degenerate map for floating-point numbers that considers close numbers as equal.

In special situations, it is possible to implement a reasonable hash for certain sets of numbers. For example, if it is known that all the floating-point values represent a number of cents, and that the floating-point numbers never contain accumulated rounding errors that reach or exceed half a cent, then each value can be rounded to the nearest cent (or the representable value nearest that) before hashing. Note that the domain of values in this case is really a discrete set, such as a set of fixed-point numbers, not a continuous set such as the set of real numbers that floating-point arithmetic is intended to approximate. In this case, the only modification that is needed is to quantize the floating-point value (round it to the nearest member of the set) before inserting it into the map. No custom hash function or equality comparison is needed.